# Recurrent sequence task

Tags: python

Given the sequence *f0, f1, f2, ...* given by the recurrence relations *f0 = 0, f1 = 1, f2 = 2* and *fk = f (k-1) + f (k-3)*

Write a program that calculates the n elements of this sequence with the numbers k1, k2, ..., kn.

**Input format**

The first line of the input contains an integer n (1 <= n <= 1000)
The second line contains n non-negative integers ki (0 <= ki <= 16000), separated by spaces.

**Output format**

Output space-separated values ​​for fk1, fk2, ... fkn.

*Memory Limit: 10MB*

*Time limit: 1 second*

The problem is that the recursive function at large values ​​goes beyond the limit.

```
def f (a):
    if a <= 2:
        return a
    return f (a - 1) + f (a - 3)


n = int (input ())
nums = list (map (int, input (). split ()))
for i in range (len (nums)):
    if i <len (nums) - 1:
        print (f (nums [i]), end = '')
    else:
        print (f (nums [i]))
```

I also tried to solve through a cycle, but the task does not go through time (1 second):

```
fk1 = 0
fk2 = 0
fk3 = 0
n = int (input ())
nums = list (map (int, input (). split ()))
a = []
for i in range (len (nums)):
    itog = 0
    for j in range (1, nums [i] + 1):
        if j <= 2:
            itog = j
        else:
            if j == 3:
                itog = 0 + 2
                fk1 = itog
                fk2 = 2
                fk3 = 1
            else:
                itog = fk1 + fk3
                fk1, fk2, fk3 = itog, fk1, fk2
    if i <len (nums) - 1:
        print (itog, end = '')
    else:
        print (itog)
```

How else can you solve this problem so that it is optimal in time and memory?

Comment: Hint: `from functools import lru_cache`

Comment: If you're going to use recursion, then you have to use memoization to maintain reasonable performance.  But an iterative approach is even faster (and doesn't grow the stack).  You should also not have to keep more than 3 values from the sequence around (other than the results).  If you sort k1...kn at the start, then you can just skip to the first one, save the value, then skip to the second one, etc.  When you have them all, apply the inverse of the sort to obtain the desired result order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the memory, the best solution probably is the iterative one. I think you are not far from the answer. The idea would be to first check for the simple cases *f(k) = k* (ie, *k <= 2*), for all other cases *k > 2* you can simply compute *fi* using (*fi-3, fi-2, fi-1*) until *i = k*. What you need to do during this process is indeed to keep track of the last three values (similar to what you did in the line `fk1, fk2, fk3 = itog, fk1, fk2`).

On the other hand, there is one thing that you need to do here. If you just perform computations of *fk1, fk2, ... fkn* independently, then you are screwed (unless you use a super fast machine or a Cython implementation). On the other hand, there is no reason to perform *n* independent computations, you can just compute fx for x = *max(k1, k2, ..., kn)* and on the way you'll store every answer for *fk1, fk2, ..., fkn* (this will slow down the computation of *fx* by a little bit, but instead of doing this n times you'll do it only once). This way it can be solved under 1s even for *n = 1000*.

On my machine, independent calculations for *f15000, f15001, ..., f16000* takes roughly 30s, the "all at once" solution takes roughly 0.035s.

Honestly, that's not such an easy exercise, it would be interesting to show your solution on a site like [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback on your solution once you found one :).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to sort the numbers. Then calculate values of the sequence one by one:

```py
while True:
    a3 = a2 + a0
    a0 = a3 + a1
    a1 = a0 + a2
    a2 = a1 + a3
```

Lastly, return values in beginning order. To do that you have to remember position of every number. From `[45, 22, 14, 33]` make `[[45,0], [22,1], [14,2], [33,3]]` and then sort, calculate values and change them with argument `[[f45,0], [f22,1], [f14,2], [f33,3]]`, then sort by second value.